# get value with flask from an html select tag

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new to Flask and I am having trouble getting the value from the select tag.I am making a calculator I tried `action = request.form('act')'and` action = request.form.get('act')', but they both give me `cannot access local variable 'action' where it is not associated with a value`

Here is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

def add(x , y):
    return(x + y)

def subtract(x , y):
    return(x - y)

def multiply(x , y):
    return(x * y)

def divide(x , y):
    return(x / y)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/calc', methods=["POST","GET"])
def calc():
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = request.form("1nm")
        num2 = request.form("2nm")
        action = request.form("act")
        return redirect(url_for('value', value=val))
    if action == 1 :
       val =  add(num1, num2) 
    elif action == 2 :
       val =  subtract(num1, num2) 
    elif action == 3 :
       val =  multiply(num1, num2)
    elif action == 4 :
        val = divide(num1, num2)    
    else:   
        return render_template("calc.html")


@app.route("/value")
def value(value):
    return f"<h1>Value:{value}</h1>"

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80, debug=True)
```

And my HTML code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{%block content%}
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="1nm" placeholder="1st Number"/>  
<label form="act">
<select name="act" id="act">
    <option value="" >select one</option>
    <option value="1" >Add</option>
    <option value="2" >Subtract</option>
    <option value="3" >Multiply</option>
    <option value="4" >Divide</option>
</select></label>
<input type="text" name="2nm" placeholder="2nd Number"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
{%endblock%}
```

I am new to Flask and kind of know Python so I am sorry for my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see many small issues which may lead to this -

First up, calc() should look somewhat like this -

```
@app.route('/calc', methods=["POST","GET"])
def calc():
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = int(request.form.get("1nm"))
        num2 = int(request.form.get("2nm"))
        action = int(request.form.get("act"))
        val = 0
        if action == 1 :
           val = add(num1, num2)
        elif action == 2 :
           val = subtract(num1, num2)
        elif action == 3 :
           val = multiply(num1, num2)
        elif action == 4 :
            val = divide(num1, num2)
        return redirect(url_for('value',value = val))

    return render_template("calc.html")
```

Since, the value put in will be taken as a string, we must first convert it to a integer. Secondly, we must use request.form.get('form attribute') to get the required number/option.

Finally value() should look like this

```
@app.route("/value/<value>")
def value(value):
    return f"<h1>Value:{value}</h1>"
```

We must pass in the value while routing to the value() function